# How do I serve static files with Go Chi?

Tags: go, go-chi

I'm learning Go and I'm having a trouble serving static files with my server. I always get 404.

The request is for `http://localhost:3001/static/breakfast.jpg`

**Router + fileServe**r

```
mux := chi.NewRouter()    
mux.Get("/", handlers.Repo.Home)
fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
mux.Handle("/static/*", http.StripPrefix("/static", fileServer))
```

**Static files path**

```
root/static/
```

My **template** homepage.tmpl

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{define "content"}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Hi from home page</h1>
            <img src="/static/breakfast.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="house" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried: `http.Dir("../../static/")` ?

Comment: Where do you tell it to use port 3001?

Comment: in main.go


const port = "127.0.0.1:3001"
serve := &http.Server{
  Addr:    port,
  Handler: routes(&appConfig),
 }

 err = serve.ListenAndServe()
 log.Fatal(err)

Comment: If the absolute path of the static folder on filesystem is `/static`, then just remove the dot on your current path to `http.Dir`.

Comment: @Niloct that worked indeed ... thank you, but I dont understand why ... the http.FileServer() takes relative path to what?

Comment: Not sure, but this: https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/how-does-http-dir-work/9203/3 tells that it's relative from the directory from which you run the `main.go` file. If you pass the absolute path then it's easier to understand. Beware of some caveats with `http.Dir` as stated here: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Dir

Comment: That would make sense, thank you! .... Would you write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [source](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/how-does-http-dir-work/9203/3) tells that `http.Dir` serves the file relatively from the directory from which you run the `main.go` file. If you pass the absolute path then it's independent from this and easier to understand by just reading the code:

`http.Dir("/static/")`

(since this is the absolute path on filesystem in your case).

Beware of some caveats with `http.Dir` as stated [here](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Dir):

(i.e. its directory separator is os-dependent, the method can follow dangerous symlinks, and could list files beginning with a dot and expose sensitive directories like `.git`)